# Angular Observables - related endpoints

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have endpoint, which returns an endpoint url.

```
http://example.com/get-endpoint
```

I want to invoke first GET and then using the result url invoke the second GET.
How can I achieve this using chained observables and RxJS? I don't know how to pass url of the first GET to the second GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RxJS's [switchMap operator](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap).

```
// your service...
getData(){
  return this.httpClient.get('http://example.com/get-endpoint', { responseType: "text"}).pipe(
    switchMap(url => this.httpClient.get(url))
  );
}
```

If your endpoint does not return a string but JSON, you should remove the `{ responseType: "text"}` option object, and pass the right property to the inner `this.httpClient.get` call.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `flatMap`:

```
this.http.get('http://example.com/get-endpoint')
    .pipe(
        flatMap(endpoint => this.service.getObservable(result))
     )
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap#examples)